# MSSQL image data is returned as text

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I am updating a CGI application that accesses an MSSQL 2008 database containing customer data. The database is managed by a third-party application, so I cannot change the data structure.

One of the tables ('guests') contains a column 'mug_shot' of type 'Image'. The column contains a JPEG image of each guest. When I retrieve data from this column, it always appears to be in text format. For example, when I perform the following query:

```
my $mugshotQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 mug_shot FROM guests where guest_no = ?";
my $mugshotStatementHandle = $dbh->prepare($mugshotQuery);
$mugshotStatementHandle->execute($guest_number);
```

and fetch the data:

```
my $mugshotHash = $mugshotStatementHandle->fetchrow_hashref();
```

`$mugshotHash->{mug_shot}` contains a hexadecimal representation of the JPEG binary data. Here is a shortened example:

```
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
```

Therefore, my attempt to display the image fails:

```
print STDOUT "Content-type: image/jpeg\n";
print STDOUT "Content-length: \n\n";
binmode STDOUT;
print STDOUT $mugshotHash->{mug_shot};
```

The browser reports that the image is invalid. Why is the data returned as text/hexadecimal instead of binary data, and what can I do to fetch the binary data?

Comment: For what it is worth, I am familiar with the pitfalls of storing blob/image data in a database and would change the storage structure if I could. Unfortunately, that is not an option in this case.

Comment: That has probably happened because the column was bound as a char instead of binary. This could happen for 2 reasons. 1. the version of DBD::ODBC you are using (but I'm guessing there) is too old 2. DBD::ODBC does not recognise the column type so falls back to binding it as a char. I'd need to know the version of DBD::ODBC you are using and what DBD::ODBC sees as the column type. You can do the latter by running your example again but set DBI_TRACE=15=x.log first and the debug will be written to x.log.

Comment: @bohica Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It turns out that there is an easy way to fetch image columns as binary instead of char: `$dbh->{syb_binary_images} = 1;`

Comment: In the future it would be worth saying which DBD you are using as this makes all the difference. Glad you are going now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a flag to return image data in binary format:

```
$dbh->{syb_binary_images} = 1;
```

After I set this flag, the images are returned in the correct format. For good measure, I also used the following to make sure that the images are not truncated:

```
$dbh->{LongTruncOK} = 0;
$dbh->do("set textsize 1000000");
```